# Show toast with Application context before Activity appears

Tags: android, android-toast

Inside `onCreate` of `Application` class, I set its instance to a static field, then show all application `Toast`s through this context. All works good except one thing, in some places a `Toast` can be shown before first activity can even appear but `Toast` never appears or sometimes just flashes. I think its because Activity not shown or drawn yet ? Or I'm missing something.

**Edit:**
More like showing toast from `onCreate` of `Application` class

**Edit 2 :**

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test from App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was talking about `onCreate` of `Application`.

Comment: When Activity is started and application is not loaded, then both onCreate() methods will be called.

But for subsequent starts of Activity, the onCreate() of application will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a `Toast` without the application even started manually by the user you can register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which listens to the BOOT_COMPLETED system broadcast and then start a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) which will handle your `Toast`s.

You'll find many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5439320/3160089) on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To make a **Toast** before drawing your layout resources, just do this following.

```
//put this code before your setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

  Toast.makeText(yourclassName.this,"your text here",5000).show();
```

Well, consider one thing. If you want this toast to be shown before loading your activity and notify users some message. Then it might not be possible always. Because, The time **Toast** is shown with fraction of nano/mili seconds your layout is being loaded as-well.Moreover, scenario is totally different when you are on a real device and on a emulator.This might be the cause you got a flash of your **Toast** message. Just run it on a real device and you will see the differences.

Hope that helps

Comment: I just want to show `Toast` as application start, no matter if something else shown or not. And `Toast` doesn't appear from `onCreate` of `Application`(not of `Activity`). And sometimes it just flashes. PS : Actually I test on real device first then on emulator.